# FbGraph2 Missing friends who use the app when querying me.friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fb-graph

I am getting only partial results for friends who use the app when I do:

```
u = User.find("user")
FbGraph2::User.me(u.facebook_access_token).fetch.friends
```

I know for sure that quite a few are missing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I used the gem Koala which solved this problem